# I keep getting a "name" error with Selenium. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

What have I done wrong? I keep getting this error:

> ============== RESTART: C:\Users\Redacted\Desktop\Autonav_1.py ==============
>   E
>       ======================================================================
>       ERROR: test_autonav_1 (**main**.Autonav_1)
>       ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\Users\Redacted\Desktop\Autonav_1.py", line 8, in setUp
>           self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "Redacted")
>       NameError: name 'selenium' is not defined
>
> Ran 1 test in 0.003s
>        FAILED (errors=1)
>
> ---

Code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
import unittest, time, re

class Autonav_1(unittest.TestCase):
def setUp(self):
    self.verificationErrors = []
    self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox" "redacted")
    self.selenium.start() 


def test_autonav_1(self):
    sel = self.selenium
    sel.open("/hub/login.php")
    sel.type("id=Email", "redacted")
    sel.type("id=Password", "redacted")
    sel.click("id=Login")
    sel.wait_for_page_to_load("30000")
    sel.click("link=Internet Retailing")
    sel.wait_for_page_to_load("30000")
    sel.click("id=redacted")
    sel.click("id=redacted")
    sel.wait_for_page_to_load("30000")

def tearDown(self):
    self.selenium.stop()
    self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
unittest.main()
```

Comment: Where exactly do you think you've defined name `selenium`? The only name imported from selenium package was `webdriver`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selenium` is the library. You need to use `webdriver`

```
def setUp(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox("localhost", 4444, "*firefox" "redacted")

def test_autonav_1(self):
    driver = self.driver
```

Comment: Doing that returns this error: E


 self.webdriver = webdriver.Firefox("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "redacted")
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 109, in __init__
    if capabilities.get("binary"):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: @MoeK Try `self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()`

Comment: @MoeK Are you using the last selenium version? If not try to update.

Answer (score 0):

You are importing `webdriver` from the `selenium` library so the name `selenium` is not bound to anything.

```
import selenium.webdriver

driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome('localhost', 4444, '*firefox', '...')
```

or

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('localhost', 4444, '*firefox', '...')
```

An `import` directive introduces a name binding for whatever is to the right of the `import` keyword.  In the first example, two names are bound -- `selenium` and `selenium.webdriver`.  In the second example only a single name is bound.  See the [python docs on import](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import) for more details.